# Compare degrees of a finite extension of domains and quotient domains

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A \subset B$ be a finite (finite type + integral) extension of integral domains and let $\mathfrak{p} \subset A, \mathfrak{q} \subset B$ be prime ideals such that $\mathfrak{q} \bigcap A =\mathfrak{p}$. Let $A/\mathfrak{p} \subset B/\mathfrak{q}$ be the induced inclusion of domains. Suppose $A$ is integrally closed.

Here is my question:

Is $A/\mathfrak{p} \subset B/\mathfrak{q}$ always a finite extension? If so, do we have $[K(B):K(A)] \ge [K(B/\mathfrak{q}):K(A/\mathfrak{p})]$?

PS: I only know this result is trivial in algebraic geometry (for varieties over a field $k$, [Fulton]'s intersection theory has a very nice formula on comparing the degrees with the ramification indices. I believe this is also easy when $K(B/\mathfrak{q})/K(A/\mathfrak{p})$ is a simple extension. But I am curious how general can it be. )

PS2: I still don't know how to prove the general case. If $K(B/\mathfrak{q})/K(A/\mathfrak{p})$ is separable, then this is a result of [Atiyah,MacDonald, Proposition 5.15].

Comment: The answer first question is trivially positive. For the second, it is true if $A$ is noetherian and normal, but false in general (think of the normalization).

Comment: @Angelo Thank you! I try to write a proof myself.  The condition A being normal is necessary, but I don't know why we need to assume noetherian. Would you please explain a little bit more? Thank you!

Comment: I still don't understand how to figure out this problem. Anyone knows?